# R group_by different column names in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr

```
student <- data.frame(ID = c(11, 12, 13),
                      Name = c("Devin", "Edward", "Wenli"),
                      Gender = c("M", "M", "F"),
                      Birthdate = c("1984-12-29", "1983-5-6", "1986-8-8"))

selection <- c("Name", "Gender", "Birthdate")
```

Now I would like to write a loop

```
library(dplyr)
for(choice in selection){
   df = group_by(choice)
   print(df)
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: You must first evaluate "choice" in the group_by function.  Try substituting in: `eval(choice)`

Comment: Why not just `df <- df %>% group_by(Name, Gender, Birthdate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, this is what you are after?

```
library(dplyr)
for(choice in selection){
  student %>% group_by(!!choice ) %>% print()
}
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
> # Groups:   "Name" [1]
>      ID Name   Gender Birthdate  `"Name"`
>   <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>      <chr>   
> 1  11.0 Devin  M      1984-12-29 Name    
> 2  12.0 Edward M      1983-5-6   Name    
> 3  13.0 Wenli  F      1986-8-8   Name    
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
> # Groups:   "Gender" [1]
>      ID Name   Gender Birthdate  `"Gender"`
>   <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>      <chr>     
> 1  11.0 Devin  M      1984-12-29 Gender    
> 2  12.0 Edward M      1983-5-6   Gender    
> 3  13.0 Wenli  F      1986-8-8   Gender    
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
> # Groups:   "Birthdate" [1]
>      ID Name   Gender Birthdate  `"Birthdate"`
>   <dbl> <fct>  <fct>  <fct>      <chr>        
> 1  11.0 Devin  M      1984-12-29 Birthdate    
> 2  12.0 Edward M      1983-5-6   Birthdate    
> 3  13.0 Wenli  F      1986-8-8   Birthdate
> ```

Note that the OP has only requested to `group_by()` but not `summarize()`.

#### Explanation of the `!!` operator

The vignette on [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) says:

> In dplyr (and in tidyeval in general) you use !! to say that you want
> to unquote an input so that it’s evaluated, not quoted.

Comment: @Magica, I have updated my answer, hope it does help.